# Performance issue: Load data infile is making select query slow

Tags: php, mysql, performance, yii

I have a program which scans twitter, facebook, google+ 24 hours a day. Per user a searchlist is running and inserted with (100 results at one time, function runs in a loop untill there are not futher results)

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand(
     "LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/tmp/inboxli_user".$user.".txt'
      INTO TABLE inbox
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',$%'
      LINES STARTING BY 'thisisthebeginningxxx'
          (created_on, created_at, tweet, tweet_id, profile_image,
           twitter_user_id, screenname, followers, lang, tags, type,
           positive_score, readme, answered, deleted, searchlist_id,
           handled_by, used_as_newsitem,  user_id)
     "                       )->execute();
```

into the database in order to keep the load as small as possible on the server. How ever when my functions are doing the bulk insert, my select functions runs very slow. Normally the inbox loads within 1.5 second but when the insertion is running sometimes it takes like 20 seconds for a page to open.

My question how can i optimize this? So insertion and select can use the database at the same time without slowing things down?

Comment: UPDATE: I notice if like only 5 new news items are inserted into the database in my myisam table the first time it loads slow and the second time not. So maybe load in file doesnot insert the indexes the right way?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1):

- Get off MyISAM!  Use InnoDB; it does a much better job of not locking out other actions.
- Load data is very efficient, increase the count to, say, 500.
- What indexes do you have?  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  `DROP` any unnecessary indexes; this will speed up the `LOAD`.
- Consider turning off the Query cache.

Comment: +1 for this comment turning off query caching helped a lot http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-in-select.html SQL_NO_CACHE adding this in the select statement, now the select doesnot slow down anymore, InnoDB i was already using  / indexes were set good and i did some small modification on my.cnf for innodb optimalization.

Comment: `SELECT` _does_ slow down, just not as much.  Furthermore, in a system with lots of 'simultaneous' connections _every_ select will hit a QC Mutex before it realizes that it won't use the QC.  This was not a problem is single-core machines when the QC was invented; but it is a big problem for heavily used 32-core machines.

Comment: The way to _really_ turn it off is `query_cache_type = OFF` _and_ `query_cache_size = 0`.

Comment: Thanks for the explination Rick, has been more than helpfull, i just corrected this and things running good now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you should make sure you indexed your table correctly. See [How does database indexing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108/how-does-database-indexing-work)

that will speed up the select statements pretty much.

Second, it's possible that you split your file into multiple chunks. So the database server removes the caches and logs for each new file you loaded.

See: https://www.percona.com/blog/2008/07/03/how-to-load-large-files-safely-into-innodb-with-load-data-infile/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however the table is good indexed and also the text file only contains 100 results each time it inserts. So its seems unlikely that this is the case.